# Get complete logs in tomcat console in catalina.out

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

I have scenario where I develop my liferay portlets through eclipse deploy them on tomcat server integrated in eclipse. Whenever I get an exception, I am able to trace it through console as the complete stacktrace is displyed there.

But, when i deploy the same portlets on to my stage and production server I am not able to see any exception in the command prompt / terminal / putty where catalina.out is displayed live.

Please tell me a way to achieve that or a workaround that. If possible, please state the merits and demerits for the same.

Comment: do you have any loggers configured in your application? Log4j, Slf4J etc.

Comment: Hi Nikhil,
Can you tell me how to check it?

Comment: Check if there is any log4j.xml or log4j.properties file in your classpath. Listeners for logging are also configured inside web.xml of a web application.

Comment: Hi Nikhil,
My log4j.properties file contains - 

log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}:%L] %m%n

Comment: You need to have these same properties for the tomcat server on staging/production. This file is usually located at \conf folder where tomcat is installed

Comment: Actually this is my production properties file. And we we dont keep this file in /conf. We keep it in tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes because we use liferay integrated tomcat. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Is a log4j listener configured in your web.xml?

Comment: log4j is not found in my web.xml but still I get all exceptions on eclipse but nothing on the Cmd prompt / unix terminal console.